Time interval in a survival model
To employ a Cox regression, we can use the following function in R as an example.

coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ sex, data = lung)

If we have a time-dependent covariate, we need to set up a special dataset in a format known as the counting process format.
Suppose we have the following data.
T1 and delta1 are the time and event indicator variables. 
TA and deltaA are time and event indicators for a secondary disease.

##   my_id   T1 delta1   TA deltaA
## 1     1 2081      0   67      1
## 2     2 1602      0 1602      0
## 3     3 1496      0 1496      0
## 4     4 1462      0   70      1
## 5     5 1433      0 1433      0

We need to change the structure of the data to the following format to include a time-dependent covariate in the Cox regression.
##   my_id   T1 delta1 tstart tstop death agvhd
## 1     1 2081      0      0    67     0     0
## 2     1 2081      0     67  2081     0     1
## 3     2 1602      0      0  1602     0     0
## 4     3 1496      0      0  1496     0     0
## 5     4 1462      0      0    70     0     0
## 6     4 1462      0     70  1462     0     1
## 7     5 1433      0      0  1433     0     0

coxph(
  Surv(time = tstart, time2 = tstop, event = death) ~ agvhd, 
  data = td_dat
  ) %>% 
  tbl_regression(exp = TRUE)

*My question is: why do we need to define the interval (add the tstart) to apply the Cox regression? Why can’t the Surv function be run just by including the tstop (Like the following fucntion)? What is the role of tstart in the calculation as we know the exact time (tstop) when the event happend?
  coxph(Surv(time=tstop, event = death) ~ agvhd, data = .) 


In a Cox regression, at each event time the covariate values for the individual having the event are compared against the values in place for all the individuals at risk at that time. The counting process format keeps track of the covariate values for an individual at all times prior to the event, so that the correct covariate values are used for all those at risk at each event time.
For the case of my_id = 1 in your example, that specifies agvhd = 0 for times through 67, with agvhd = 1 thereafter. Even though my_id = 1 never has the event in your example, it's important to have the correct agvhd value for that individual at all the times that others have the event in the study. I suppose that there might be alternative ways for software to keep track of covariate values that change over time, but the counting process format is simple, works reliably, and extends nicely to more complicated scenarios like multi-state models.
In response to comments
I suppose that in simple situations there could be a way for software to use data with "a separate row for each value of the covariate with the corresponding value of time" as you propose. Your proposal might work OK if you knew that the end of one interval for an individual was always the start of the next interval for that individual.
You can't always count on that, however; you need to allow for more general left truncation patterns in data. (Left truncation means that the row of data provides no information prior to the start of the time interval.) Thus functions like coxph() in the R survival package use the counting-process data format to handle time-varying covariate values (which nicely extends to many other types of survival models, like multi-state models).
It's important not to confuse two different types of time intervals in survival analysis.
In the counting process format, the interval for an individual is known to start at some defined time, to have constant covariate values through the time interval, and to end at an event time or a censoring time.
Interval censoring means something else. Interval censoring means you only know that the event happened at some time within the interval, but you don't know the exact time.
Counting-process and interval-censored data rows have both a start time and a stop time for each interval. Software settings distinguish interval censoring from counting-process intervals. For example, in the R survival package, the Surv() function has a type argument. If there are both start and stop times the default value is type="counting" but you can specify "interval" instead if necessary for your data.
The R coxph() function can't handle interval censoring, however. If your data are interval censored and you need to fit a Cox model, you need tools like those in the R icenReg package.

First, I am very thankful for your time. I could not fully understand your point. In my understanding, a Cox regression with a time-dependent covariate, when time has a continuous format and with right censoring, means we know exactly when the event happened. As we have a time-dependent covariate, we need to create a long dataset with multiple times for the different covariate values for each patient. So, why not make a separate row for each value of the covariate with the corresponding value of time? What is the point of adding tstart to the model?

When we know that just for id=1, at time 2081, due to different values of the covariate, the value of the event may have a different status. By adding an interval to the data, we change the structure of the model from Cox regression with right censoring to interval censoring.

@elisa I added a bit to the answer to try to clarify. Don't forget that the time and covariate values for an individual in a Cox model are used not only for that individual but also for all other individuals who are at risk at the same times. One way or another, the software needs to keep track of all covariate values over time for all at-risk individuals. It might be possible to implement your suggestion to do that, but the counting-process format nicely handles not only time-varying covariate values but also many other situations that can be evaluated by survival analysis.

thank you so much for your time.
